# SciKitLearn OLS regression on categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm running regression on a dataframe which has some regular value columns and some categorical ones.

I've successfully used pandas.get_dummies on the categorical columns and run OLS on the concatenated dataframe, but the results list every dummy column separately, and of course I want to re-unite them for the correlation.

Here's how I'm currently doing it:
(X is an existing array with all the numerical columns normalized)

```
obj_df = df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).copy()
one_hot = pd.get_dummies(obj_df, columns=["CategoryColumn1","CategoryColumn2", "CategoryColumn3"])
df.drop(["CategoryColumn1","CategoryColumn2", "CategoryColumn3"], axis=1, inplace=True)

df_new = pd.concat([X, one_hot], axis=1)
df_new.drop(["StartDateTime"], axis=1, inplace=True)
df_new.head()

est = sm.OLS(y.astype(float), df_new.astype(float)).fit()
est.summary()
```

Comment: How would you like to re-unite them? Let say one dummy variable got a coefficient of 0.5, and another one got -0.7. What would you like the united coefficient to be?

Comment: I don't know-it seems as though there should be some measure of how significantly the original category affects the labeled data. If I'm using machine learning to determine how much the size and type of a beer affect customer satisfaction, and I have 500 different beer brands, do I really need 500 different numbers? I can't conclude something about the significance of the beer brand in general?

Comment: Yes, you could see which one of your 500 beer brands had the greatest weight and impact in your model by dumping the coefficients with est.coef_

Comment: This is just using the ordinary least squares method of predicting a continuous variable (your y) based off other values. If you want to know which one of the 500 brands has the greatest impact on your y then yes, you must keep them as separate variables in the classic linear regression model. Consider: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Classical_linear_regression_model). But consider, different brands have different taste profiles, and other variables in your dataset ( bitterness, price) will be highly correlated with your "brand" variable

Comment: I guess you want the R2 for the whole model

Comment: @DirkNachbar-I was looking for something like R-squared, but separately for each category. 

Let me explain. Let's say I have one column for beer brands, another for venue in which beer was drunk, a third for cost of beer, and a fourth for drinker satisfaction. Once I categorize brands and venue, I can run regression-but then I still have no idea how the brand AS A WHOLE and the venue AS A WHOLE affect drinker satisfaction. And if I take R-squared, it will take cost into account, and just lump everything together.